# Lazily serving Django static content with NGINX

Tags: django, nginx

Let's say I've got Django code rooted in `/var/my_app`. I've got a `MEDIA_ROOT` configured at `/var/my_app/files`, and `MEDIA_URL` is `/var/my_app/files` at `/files`. Serving these files through UWSGI (or gunicorn, etc.) works fine.

Now I am trying to use the NGINX `try_files` directive to serve them without hitting UWSGI. Here's what I've got:

```
location /files/* {
  try_files /var/my_app$uri $uri;
}
```

Wherein my understanding is that if I am attempting to access `$hostname/files/photos/thumbs/file.jpg`, the above `location` matches, `$uri` is `/files/photos/thumbs/file.jpg`, NGINX tests `/var/my_app/files/photos/thumbs/file.jpg` and should return the file if it exists.

Instead, when I access that URI, I see the request passed through to UWSGI in the UWSGI log, even though the file exists at `/var/my_app/files/photos/thumbs/file.jpg`. What am I doing wrong? I read the docs on [`try_files`](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#try_files), but clearly I am misunderstanding something.

For reference, here is the Django `location` block:

```
location / {
  include               uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_param           UWSGI_SETENV DATABASE_URL=[redacted]
  uwsgi_pass            127.0.0.1:3034;
}
```

**Added Context**

This configuration is targeted at lazily serving Django-generated thumbnails (using `easy-thumbnails`) if they do not yet exist.

Comment: And yeah, I've Googled this a bunch. A lot of blogs/SO answers have you use `if`, which is evil according to NGINX docs. So, sorry about posting about my specific situation, but I'm not so confident having Googled around for this.

Comment: Typo? Do you mean `try_files /var/my_app$uri $uri;`

Comment: I don't think `location /files/*` is valid because of the asterisk. Try just `location /files/`

Comment: I'd also consider moving your static file path outside the application path. You can use `manage.py` to collate all the static files inside the app into your new media directory. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Comment: @AlexHowansky no dice :<

Comment: @Basic: yes, I will be doing that. Yeah, I use `collectstatic`. Just haven't gotten to that step in this deploy yet.